# Resetting stub history fails in Sinon

Tags: node.js, sinon

I want to reset the history (number of invocations) after each test. Works fine in Webstorm IDE, fails in NPM test telling me

> State Machine Trigger "before each" hook for "invokes the step function handler if input is non empty": TypeError: stepFunctionHandler.startStepFunction.resetHistory is not a function

From what I can tell, I'm following the sinon documentation.

**Here's the code under test:**

```
const config = require('config');
const { attempt } = require('@mystuff/utils');
const stepFunctionHandler = require('../../serviceHandlers/stepFunctionHandler');
const logger = require('../../../components/logger.js');


async function trigger(event) {

  if (!event || !Object.keys(event).length) {
    throw new Error('Invalid input. Expecting a list of normalized objects but input was empty.');
  }

  logger.info(`Input event: ${event}`);

  const stateMachineARN = config.get('stateMachine.arn');
  const [error, result] = await attempt(() =>
    stepFunctionHandler.startStepFunction(stateMachineARN, event),
  );

  if (error) {
    logger.error(`Invoking state machine failed ${error}`);
    throw new Error(`Invoking state machine failed ${error}`)
  }

  return { result, statusCode: 200 };
}

module.exports = { trigger };
```

**Here's the test**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const stateMachineTriggerHandler = require('../../handler');
const stepFunctionHandler = require('../../../../serviceHandlers/stepFunctionHandler');

const event = { foo: 'bar' };

const startStepFunctionMock = sinon.stub(stepFunctionHandler, 'startStepFunction');

describe('State Machine Trigger', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    stepFunctionHandler.startStepFunction.resetHistory()
  })

  it('invokes the step function handler if input is non empty', async () => {
    startStepFunctionMock.resolves({ state: 'success' });
    await assert.doesNotReject(async () => {
      await stateMachineTriggerHandler.trigger(event);
    });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stepFunctionHandler.startStepFunction);
  });


  it('throws an error if the step function invocation failed', async () => {
    startStepFunctionMock.rejects(Error(`failed to start`));

    await assert.rejects(async () => {
      await stateMachineTriggerHandler.trigger(event);
    }, (err) => {
      assert.strictEqual(err.name, 'Error');
      assert.strictEqual(err.message, 'Invoking state machine failed Error: failed to start');
      return true;
    });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(stepFunctionHandler.startStepFunction);
  });

  it('throws an error if input is undefined', async () => {
    await assert.rejects(async () => {
      await stateMachineTriggerHandler.trigger();
    }, (err) => {
      assert.strictEqual(err.name, 'Error');
      assert.strictEqual(err.message, 'Invalid input. Expecting a list of normalized restrictions but input was empty.');
      return true;
    });
    sinon.assert.notCalled(stepFunctionHandler.startStepFunction);
  });

  it('throws an error if input is empty', async () => {
    await assert.rejects(async () => {
      await stateMachineTriggerHandler.trigger({});
    }, (err) => {
      assert.strictEqual(err.name, 'Error');
      assert.strictEqual(err.message, 'Invalid input. Expecting a list of normalized restrictions but input was empty.');
      return true;
    });
    sinon.assert.notCalled(stepFunctionHandler.startStepFunction);
  });
});
```

**Here's the stack trace coming from npm test**

```
State Machine Trigger "before each" hook for "invokes the step function handler if input is non empty":
     TypeError: stepFunctionHandler.startStepFunction.resetHistory is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (functions/qeTools/stateMachineTrigger/test/unit/test.js:17:43)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:137:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your stub variable in order to able to call [resetHistory()](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stubresethistory), which you have already defined: `startStepFunctionMock`.

So change your before each to:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  startStepFunctionMock.resetHistory();
});
```